# Situation with my login, grant access concerns. Google ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api

I have created a website in ASP.NET in which user can login with his google ID. In this implementation I have used google API.

But the problem I am facing is, each time when a user login, he has to grant permissions to website. I mean 1 time granting permission should be enough.

I know it is something related to refresh token but I have no idea how it is done. Can someone please help?

Comment: you will need to post your code before someone can help you debug it.

Comment: ok here i m confused now..every user will have a different refresh token right?..if i ll have multiple refresh token then if a user is trying to login how ill i knw which is user is trying to log in and which refresh token i have to use?

Comment: Exactly everyone has a different refreshtoken

Comment: ok that is cool..maybe i can save there refresh token in the cookies or something ..i guess it ll work